# How to resize master page div from content page

Tags: asp.net, html, master-pages

How would I go about resizing a div from a page to it's master page?

Making the div a server side control doesn't seem to be an option as all applied css breaks from the name change and I cannot modify the css file.

I have tried the solution below from Hunter using the MasterType and then creating a property in my base master page, but my content page does not see the public property.

I have three files involved listed in their hierarchal structure.

1) Base master page where div resides
2) Master page for section of site
3) Content page for which I need to change the div in #1

Comment: Accepting hunter's answer, it turns out, I was expecting auto complete to kick in with my new property in my base page. IT DOESN'T. I typed this out this.Master.Master.DivWith and walla it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could trying setting the pages `MasterType`, which will let you manipulate members on the `MasterPage` directly from the page

So in your master page you could add Property like this:

```
public int DivWidth { get; set; }
```

Then on your page you can add this to the .aspx content below the `<@ Page` line:

```
<%@ MasterType TypeName="Name.Space.Master" %>
```

which is the namespace and class of your Master page.

Then on the pages code behind you should be able to set that Property like so:

```
Page.Master.DivWidth = 100;
```

More on the MasterType directive: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228274(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: How would I do this when I have a two masters? For instance, I have my content page, this has a master page, the master page has a master page.

Comment: also wouldn't this require the div to runat="server"?

Comment: You can use the same technique to pass values from nested master pages to the parent master page. The div would only need to be runat="server" if you wanted to add the width server side. You could write `<div style="width: <%=DivWidth %>;">` instead.

Comment: As i said in my question, I cannot make the div a server side control as it changes the name and causes the css to not be applied. Unless you know a way around this.

Comment: @James - if you're using .net 4, set `ClientIDMode="Static"` on the div to prevent the renaming.

Comment: Don't make it runat="server", just write `<div style="width: <%=DivWidth %>;">`

Comment: @hunter, great I am trying this but I just cannot seem to access the property from my content page. I added the mastertype. Now when I added the master type, I added the master page type of the Main parent masterpage , not the master page of the content page, since I can only add one. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @hunter, this seemed to work on my dev enviornment but live, please take a look at my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159454/how-do-i-solve-the-error-system-web-ui-masterpage-does-not-contain-a-definition

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps there is an easier (though admittedly less clean) method of doing this.  Give your div a class which is not defined in your stylesheets, and then put a style tag on your page, like so:

```
<style type="text/css">.myDivClass { width: 42px; } //or whatever width you like</style>
```

Of course, this requires that you have a header placeholder in your MasterPage.

Comment: This would be more of a mess for me as I would have to edit the main css file which I cannot do, the div contains a ton of other objects.