# How do I solve the error 'System.Web.UI.MasterPage' does not contain a definition for

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have two master pages and a content page. On my local machine this code works, but once I uploaded to the server I got the following error:

Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Web.UI.MasterPage' does not contain a definition for 'DivWidth' and no extension method 'DivWidth' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.MasterPage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

Line 84:
Line 85:
Line 86:        this.Master.Master.DivWidth = 955;
Line 87:         SimpleElementCollection restrictedIds = new SimpleElementCollection();
Line 88:         restrictedIds.Add(new SimpleElement(priceModifierPriceTypeId));

Source File: c:\Inetpub\testsite\shop\Default.aspx.cs    Line: 86

Base Masterpage cocde:

```
public partial class global : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
public int DivWidth { get; set; } 

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            SetBodyClass();
          if (DivWidth < 1)
        {
            DivWidth = 768;
        }
    }
```

Base Masterpage aspx:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="global.master.cs" Inherits="global" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
<head id="Head1" runat="server" dir="ltr" lang="en-us" profile="http://dublincore.org/documents/dcq-html/">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
<title>page title</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="en-US" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-us" />

  <link rel="Bookmark" href="#content" title="Page Content" type="text/html" />
  <link rel="Bookmark" href="#primary-navigation" title="Site Navigation" type="text/html" />

  <link href="css/screen/global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"  />
<link href="css/print/print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" />


<script src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/javascript/jquery-1.2.6.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/javascript/jquery.clearonfocus.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/javascript/modalControl.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="headPlaceholder" runat="server" />
  <!--[if IE]><link href="css/screen/ie/ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"  /><![endif]-->
  <!--[if IE 6]><link href="css/screen/ie/ie-6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"  /><![endif]-->

] 
</head>
<body id="Body" runat="server">
<div id="main">
        <div id="main-inner">
            <div id="content" style="width:<%=DivWidth%>px;"><div id="content-top"></div><div class="content-inner"><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="contentPlaceHolder" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="BelowLeftRightMainContent" runat="server" /></div> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Second Master Page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/global.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="shopFalcon.master.cs" Inherits="shopFalcon" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="FALCON" TagName="FeatureProducts" Src="~/FalconShopRightHand.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="FALCON" TagName="ProductSearch" Src="~/FalconProductSearch.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="FALCON" TagName="AbuseText" Src="~/FalconAbuseLinkDisplay.ascx" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="headPlaceholder" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

nothing in the code behind cept empty code behind

My content page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/shop.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="shopFalcon_Default" Title="Shop Homepage" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/shop.master"%>


<asp:Content ID="Content7" ContentPlaceHolderID="leftColPlaceHolder" Runat="Server">
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageAlign="Right" ImageUrl="~/images/Free+Shipping+01.jpg" CssClass="img"/>
<h1>Shop Anytime, anywhere. </h1>

<div id="shopByBrandDiv">
    </asp:Content>
```

My code behind:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            this.Master.Master.DivWidth = 955;
    }
```

Again this works in Visual Studio using the built in web server but delpoying to the production server running IIS6 I get that error stated above.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe not compiled correctly, try to full recompile your pages.

Comment: @Aristos it seemed to compile, I put two spaces in the web.config and then removed them, this normally forces a recompile.

Comment: hm, IMO this should NEVER work since you need a cast from MasterPage to your own class ((global)this.Master.Master).DivWidth = 955;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is the thing, this works sometimes and then when I add another property or recompile it would give me an error. it turns out it is compiler issue. To get around the issue, I had to create a App_Code directory under the root and made a class. When I get the error telling me there is no DivWidth defined, I simple make a code change in the class I created and the site compiles in the proper order. It took opening a case with MS, who was not very helpful, for me to find this workaround. Hope this helps someone else who runs into this strange issue.

Comment: hm, IMO this should NEVER work since you need a cast from MasterPage to your own class ((global)this.Master.Master).DivWidth = 955;

Comment: It works both ways but I have the same issue no matter with or without the cast. I declear the master type so the class knows that this.master.master is global during runtime. It also knows this.master is shop.master. Soemtimes when I try the cast I get cannot convert type global to type masterpage. So I left it this.master.master .

Answer (score 0):

```
public int DivWidth { get; set; }
```

Does this actually get implemented?

Comment: @Moo-Juice Well I would assume so, as this same code works on my local. I use it in Base Masterpage aspx and set it in that code behind and my content page

Comment: Sorry, but in your pasted-code I couldn't see anywhere that DivWidth actually did anything.

Comment: @Moo-Juice  Look again it is set in two places and called in this line in the base masterpage.aspx <div id="content" style="width:<%=DivWidth%>px;">

Comment: Yes, I saw that.  What I am saying is, the property declaration itself, given the code you have given, doesn't *do* anything.  It's just get; set;. Are you missing something you haven't pasted?

Comment: @Moo-Juice In c# 3.0 MS introduced a new syntax for a property called an auto-implemented property, which allows you to create properties without get and set accessor implementations.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPage.master" %>
```

in .aspx file