# "System.Web.UI.MasterPage does not contain a definition..." ASP.NET error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

EDIT:  The main problem seemed to be that I was just doing "Add Existing Item" from an old web site project into an ASP.NET Web Application project.  This caused so much trouble I just started from scratch, except that instead of adding existing items, I added new Master Pages and aspx pages to the project then populated them.  The same problem persists.

I have a legacy project that is just a standard web site.  I've started a new project as a web application and have transplanted in all the pages I need.  However, I'm receiving 100+ errors that are comprised mostly of slightly different permutations of the following:

- `'System.Web.UI.MasterPage does not contain a definition for 'headerImage'` (I get this in code-behind)
- `'MasterPage' does not contain a definition for 'imgHeader'` (also this is in code-behind)

Regarding the first error, it's as though the project is not comprehending that the master page is set.  I set the master page at the top of each one of my aspx pages like:

```
<%@ page language="C#" masterpagefile="~/MasterPages/MasterPage.master" autoeventwireup="true" inherits="Equipment.aspx.cs" title="Untitled Page" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPages/MasterPage.master"  %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<!-- some content -->
</asp:Content>
```

Also, I clearly expose a `headerImage` property in the ~/MasterPages/MasterPage.master code-behind:

```
   public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
   {
      #region Properties

      private string _headerImage;
      public string headerImage
      {
         get
         {
            return _headerImage;
         }
         set
         {
            _headerImage = (string)value;
         }

      }

      // other stuff
   }
```

And yet VS is still looking for this property in the System.Web.UI.MasterPage base class!

I've already checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159454/how-do-i-solve-the-error-system-web-ui-masterpage-does-not-contain-a-definitio) post and it didn't solve my problem.

Thoughts?  All feedback is appreciated.  Thanks guys.

Comment: where is the ext for this file "~/MasterPages/MasterPage.master

Comment: @DJKRAZE I'm new to VS ASP.NET.  If you mean extension, it's just .master, and .cs for the code behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good morning when you added the existing files to your new web application did you recreate them all from scratch or did you do a literal "Add Existing Item"?  If so, then you should right click on each of the files and click the "Convert To Web Application" option.

Comment: Yeah I just did "Add Existing Item."  So I just need to do "Convert" on the master pages (it's the only place I even see the option).  Thanks.

Comment: Is it not available on the other .aspx or .ascx files in the site?

Comment: Oddly it's available for some.  I went ahead and converted all the files that I could.  After I do this I get errors like "The Type 'MasterPage' already contains a definition for 'Form1'" and other items.

Comment: mreyeros has a great suggestion

Comment: By clicking on the "Convert.." option what this does is create a designer file associated to each .master, .aspx, etc..  This designer file will contain all of your control declarations for the file in question.  Make sure that in the codebehind file of each of the files that there aren't any control declarations like this:

     protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm form1;

Comment: @mreyeros Thanks I'm going to try this.

Answer (score 2):

Check what is the namespace of this.Master.
If it's `System.Web.UI.MasterPage`, try to rename your master page to a different name. This way you can isolate the problem.

Comment: This is the problem.  The transplanted in Master Pages were in _no_ namespace.  I just wrapped them with the common namespace used by this project and most of my problems went away.  Still have some "mynamespace.MasterPage already defines a member called "SomeCSS" with the same parameters."  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is similar to that of @mreyeros - however, my designer file was present already - it was that Vs didn't recognise the partial nature of the none- designer class and thus link the 2 together.

The fix I used was to remove the files from the project and re-add them using add existing. I did this in bulk and the newly added files behaved correctly and the error went away.